# Visual C++ Statement + Vars

Tags: c++-cli

How Can I bind for example int value to the statement below?

```
System::String^ Content = "just example";
int iAValue = 5;

lblOutput_{iValue}->Text = Content;
```

Comment: Have you considered using an array?

Comment: yes, but the way i want it to work is like that:
some function takes int param, and then binding it into statement to output content in proper place.
private: void getSet(iAValue, System::String^ Content) { lblOutput_{iAValue}->Text = Content; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't; you use an array or collection of some sort.  This sort of thing is often attempted by beginners.  It is not possible, nor is it a good idea to tie your program logic to the names of your variables.

```
auto labels = gcnew List<Label>();
labels->Add(lblOutput1);
labels->Add(lblOutput2);
labels->Add(lblOutput3);
labels->Add(lblOutput4);
labels->Add(lblOutput5);
// ...
String^ Content = "just example";
int iAValue = 4;
labels[iAValue].Text = Content;
```

And then later you can iterate over all of them easily:

```
for(int i = 0; i < labels->Count; ++i) {
    // i is the label "number"
    // labels[i] is the label
}
```